# Mail sending without authentication using Java Mail Api

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am following code to send mail without authentication.The java code described as follows.

```
final String frommail = "a@g.com"
 String toEmail = "b@gmail.com";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", PropertiesLoader.getPropertiesValue(MAIL_SMTP_AUTH));
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", PropertiesLoader.getPropertiesValue(MAIL_SMTP_HOST));
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", PropertiesLoader.getPropertiesValue(MAIL_SMTP_PORT));
    //enable authentication
    props.put(MAIL_SMTP_ENABLE, PropertiesLoader.getPropertiesValue(MAIL_SMTP_ENABLE));

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        //set message headers
        msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
        msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
        msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(frommail, EMAIL_FROM_NAME));
        // msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(frommail, false));
        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setContent(body, MAIL_CONTENT_TYPE);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("pramilkprince@rediffmail.com", false));
        Transport.send(msg);
        logger.info("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
```

But when sending mail, it throws following exception

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1
>   : Relay access denied    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1862)   at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1118)
>     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)   at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   com.gtl.gcc.util.SendEmail.sendEmailFromInfo(SendEmail.java:195)  at
>   com.gtl.gcc.util.SendEmail.createMailBodyAndSendMailForUpdateKYC(SendEmail.java:144)

if any one have any idea about this please help

Comment: Sorry, It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to know what "Relay access denied" means? Or do you want to send mail without authentication? (which in your case obviously won't work)

Comment: Yes I want to send mail without authentication in java.For that , what change I have to implement for the above code?I  also want to root cause of the exception

Comment: Well, for starters, you have to find another smtp server that doesn't do auth. Are you writing some sort of spam sowtware? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail without authentication, you need to run your own SMTP server.  If it's on the public internet, it will be flooded with spam before you can use it yourself.  If it's on your private intranet, you can make it work.  Gmail, for example, is definitely **not** going to let you send mail without authenticating.  Note that this has absolutely nothing at all to do with use of the JavaMail API.

Answer (score 0):

As @BillShannon pointed out, sending through most SMTP servers will require authentication due to SPAM issues.

However, the *MX Gateways* for any domain are required to be open on TCP 25 and for emails without authentication.

While working on [Java send email avoiding smtp relay server and send directly to MX server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181177/java-send-email-avoiding-smtp-relay-server-and-send-directly-to-mx-server/34182103#34182103) I created a small example to use the target domain's MX server to directly address that.

As pointed out before: If your sending server does not reverse-DNS to the domain you're sending *from*, you'll most likely end up being blocked or directly classified as spam.

Good Luck